# Rails Mongoid search parents elements that have at least one child

Tags: search, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, children

I have a rails 4 app and I have 2 objects: stores and books (referenced 1:n relation).
A store has many books, each book belongs to one store. Some stores don't have any books.
How can I make a query to find the 3 latest store that has at least 1 book - and the 3 latest stores that have no books ?

```
@stores = Store.order_by(:created_at => 'desc').limit(4).uniq
@books = Book.order_by(:created_at => 'desc').limit(4).uniq
```

This work but I don't know how to do a where(book.exists?) for store, or for the @books to make sure each book belongs to a unique store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic CRUD operations in MongoDB operate on a *single* collection,
"join" capability is not yet implemented that would allow them to operate across two collections.
Once you understand this, you can easily construct two operations that will do what you want.
The following is the most obvious given the schema hints that you supplied.
To do anything more, you probably want to consider schema changes like embedding.

By definition, your supplied schema only allows a book to belong to one (unique by definition) store.
You can see this from the inspection of the books, that there is a single value store_id for each book.
Hope that this helps your understanding.

app/models/store.rb

```
class Store
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :name, type: String

  has_many :books
end
```

app/models/book.rb

```
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  field :title, type: String

  belongs_to :store
end
```

test/unit/store_test.rb

require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

```
class StoreTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Mongoid.default_session.drop
  end
  test '0. mongoid version' do
    puts "\nMongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
  test 'store query has book, does not have book' do
    [
        ["Amazon.com", ["Outlander", "Taking It All"]],
        ["Barnes & Noble", ["Big Little Lies"]],
        ["Goodreads", []],
        ["Greenlight Bookstore", []],
        ["Powell's Books", ["Gone Girl", "Dark Skye"]],
        ["Strand Books", []]
    ].each do |store, books|
     store = Store.create(name: store)
     books.each do |title|
       store.books << Book.create(title: title)
     end
     sleep 1
    end
    assert_equal(6, Store.count)
    assert_equal(5, Book.count)
    puts
    store_ids_with_books = Book.distinct(:store_id)
    latest_stores_with_a_book = Store.in(_id: store_ids_with_books).order_by(:created_at => 'desc').limit(3).to_a
    puts "three latest stores with a book:"
    pp latest_stores_with_a_book
    latest_stores_without_a_book = Store.nin(_id: store_ids_with_books).order_by(:created_at => 'desc').limit(3).to_a
    puts "three latest stores without a book:"
    pp latest_stores_without_a_book
    puts "books:"
    pp Book.all.to_a
  end
end
```

rake test

```
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/2] StoreTest#test_0._mongoid_version
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.6
Moped::VERSION:1.5.2
[2/2] StoreTest#test_store_query_has_book,_does_not_have_book
three latest stores with a book:
[#<Store _id: 53f257287f11ba75e5000008, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:32 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:32 UTC, name: "Powell's Books">,
 #<Store _id: 53f257257f11ba75e5000004, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:29 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:29 UTC, name: "Barnes & Noble">,
 #<Store _id: 53f257247f11ba75e5000001, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:27 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:27 UTC, name: "Amazon.com">]
three latest stores without a book:
[#<Store _id: 53f257297f11ba75e500000b, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:33 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:33 UTC, name: "Strand Books">,
 #<Store _id: 53f257277f11ba75e5000007, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:31 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:31 UTC, name: "Greenlight Bookstore">,
 #<Store _id: 53f257267f11ba75e5000006, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:30 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:30 UTC, name: "Goodreads">]
books:
[#<Book _id: 53f257247f11ba75e5000002, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:28 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:28 UTC, title: "Outlander", store_id: "53f257247f11ba75e5000001">,
 #<Book _id: 53f257247f11ba75e5000003, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:28 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:28 UTC, title: "Taking It All", store_id: "53f257247f11ba75e5000001">,
 #<Book _id: 53f257257f11ba75e5000005, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:29 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:29 UTC, title: "Big Little Lies", store_id: "53f257257f11ba75e5000004">,
 #<Book _id: 53f257287f11ba75e5000009, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:32 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:32 UTC, title: "Gone Girl", store_id: "53f257287f11ba75e5000008">,
 #<Book _id: 53f257287f11ba75e500000a, created_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:32 UTC, updated_at: 2014-08-18 19:42:32 UTC, title: "Dark Skye", store_id: "53f257287f11ba75e5000008">]
Finished tests in 6.193234s, 0.3229 tests/s, 0.3229 assertions/s.             
2 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```